# Change project-properties with IWizard

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, project-template

I created a template for a VS-project where I want to set some attributes provided by the user. So I implemented `IWizard`-interface:

```
public void RunStarted(object automationObject, Dictionary<string, string> replacementsDictionary, WizardRunKind runKind, object[] customParams)
{
    string projectPath = replacementsDictionary["$destinationdirectory$"];
    string projectName = replacementsDictionary["$projectname$"];

    SchemaWizardForm frm = new SchemaWizardForm(projectPath, projectName);
    frm.ShowDialog();
    this.m_assemblyInfo = frm.AssemblyInfo;

    replacementsDictionary["$assemblyTitle$"] = frm.AssemblyInfo.AssemblyName;
    replacementsDictionary["$assemblyName$"] = frm.AssemblyInfo.AssemblyName;
    replacementsDictionary["$copyrightYear$"] = DateTime.Now.Month + "/" + DateTime.Now.Year;
    replacementsDictionary["$defaultNamespace$"] = frm.AssemblyInfo.RootNamespace;
}
```

Now within my template´s project-file I have something like this:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">x86</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>8.0.30703</ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>$defaultNamespace$</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>$assemblyName$</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v3.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment> 
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

And in `AssemblyInfo.cs`:

```
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("$assemblyTitle$")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("(C) $copyrightYear$ MyCompany")]
// ...
```

I can sucessfully create my project using the wizard. Its copyright-date from `AssemblyInfo.cs` after generation is `[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("(C) 8/2016 MyCompany")]` - which is fine. However the `RootNamespace` has a value similar to the `projectsname`. I already debugged the above code, where the `replacementsDictionary` dontains the correct entry for the namespace (see image below).

[image: although the map has the correct values the result-project does not have those properties set appropriately]

Here is the result-project

[image]

As you can see both the `Assembly Name` and the `Default namespace` contain the value from `projectsname` instead of what I entered in my user-form (`asdas` in my case). However the copyright-date accessable via the `Assembly Information`-button at **Project-->Propertes-->Application** is set correctly (not shown in the image).

Isn´t it possible to change the projects properties themeselfes using a `replacementDictionary`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously we can´t change the project´s properties via such a dictionary. What we can do instead is to modify the `projectname`-entry within this map which solved the issue for me. Now `Assembly title`, `Assembly name` and `Default namespace` all refer to that same variable. It is a bit annoying (in particular that we can´t change the name of the assembly and the namespace independently) but this works for me.

```
replacementsDictionary["$projectname$"] = frm.AssemblyInfo.ProjectName;
replacementsDictionary["$safeprojectname$"] = frm.AssemblyInfo.ProjectName;
```